# Errors in production use while deployment/validation is running

Tags: unit-test, deployment, change-set

During the validation or deployment of a change set, you cannot edit Salesforce metadata. I understand why this is necessary.

But sometimes, users cannot edit some *records* during the validation or deployment. This does not affect all objects or all users.

Examples:

- Users edit cases, which causes some triggers to fire. This error message is shown: "Your request exceeded the time limit for processing." (This only happens during deployments or deployment validations, and not for all case updates.)
- Users edit a record and get the message that the record is in use by a different user. (This sometimes happens while unit tests are running, but hardly ever when they don't run.)
- While changing a custom setting through apex: "UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record" (often during deployments/validations, hardly ever while not deploying)

Can someone explain why this happens? I guess that it depends on the contents of the deployment (change set components) and what the user action triggers (workflow rules, processes, apex code etc.). I'd like to avoid this if possible so that my users are not affected by deployments.

Comment: what error do the users get?

Comment: I will come back with the error message when it happens again. I know that the users tried to save changes, that saving took very long (the time when the Save and Cancel buttons are deactivated) and that it finally failed with an error message.

Comment: I have added examples to my question.

Comment: Examples 2 and 3 look like scenarios where the testmethods are relying on org data `seeAllData=true` or test classes at V23 or below

Comment: Hi crop1645, a few of our unit tests do use seeAllData because they need access to a custom setting in a managed package, but these are just about 10 unit tests out of 600 in total. So seeAllData could be the reason for sporadic errors, but they occur rather often during deployments.